# I want puranas in TRANSLITERATED format.transliteration of Sanskrit into roman script

Tags: scripture, puranas, resource, book-recommendation

Ebooks, online or books for purchase also acceptable. Please can anyone help me? Links to all major scriptures is what i need.Thank you!

Comment: All the answers have english translations bros which i dont want.

Comment: The question you guys thought this was duplicate of asks about translation and i asked about transliteration. You people clearly misunderstood.

Comment: Check all the sites mentioned in the target duplicates. Especially second one. The answer has links to websites which have scriptures in IAST ask Roman Transliteration..

Comment: I am looking for shiva purana in particular in roman script, so can i ask a question about individual purana?

Comment: You may ask but It is possible it will be closed as a duplicate eventually. That post is working as a target post when looking for resources. Please use @username when replying to users.